# Turn off chunked encoding for Wordpress RSS feed?

Tags: php, wordpress, actionscript-3, http, rss

Firstly sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, but I can't find anything close to this.

For various reasons, I am importing an RSS feed into flash to get its content. Everything works fine, except that I can't get the size of the RSS file when loading it (via `URLLoader` and `getBytesTotal`. After some research I found that the feed itself it chunked, which as I understand it (and I am a novice at this!) means flash (evidently) can't access the file size of the feed because of the way it's being transferred. So my question is, *can I turn this chunked encoding off*, either on the server or in flash?

Failing this, is it possible to write some server code (perhaps php) that would periodically download and store the feed itself as a regular XML file?

Apologies if this post is vague, I'm very unfamiliar with this topic and there isn't any relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

To receive "normal" output, send out an HTTP/1.0 request instead of an HTTP/1.1 in Flash. This forces the server to respond with an HTTP/1.0 response. HTTP/1.0 will never respond with chunked encoding, because HTTP/1.0 does not support chunked encoding.